# TcpClient/TcpListener: Implentación comunicación por comandos

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación cliente/servidor donde utilizo clases TCPListener y TcpClient para la comunicación entre puntos. Básicamente, la aplicación tiene que sincronizar la carpeta favoritos de ambas máquinas. La comunicación es bidireccional, es decir, el cliente puede comunicarse con el servidor y opcionalmente recibir una respuesta y viceversa. Había pensado realizar la comunicación basandome en comandos. Por ejemplo, un comando para pedir la lista de favoritos de la otra parte, otro para pedir los ficheros per se, y otra para mandar un mensaje. Los 2 primeros comandos requieren respuesta, el otr no.

Cómo podría plantear todo esto de forma genérica, de tal manera que pueda implementar un posible nuevo comando en el futuro, hacer que el cliente o servidor lo envíe, y pueda recibir la respusta adecuada?

**EDITO:** Incluyo código. Hasta aquí ambas clases pueden comunicarse solo vía strings. Quién las consume, también puede hacer uso de los eventos para capturar los datos recibidos o enviados. Sé que ambas partes son similares y se podría refactorizar. Pero antes necesito tener claro como comunicarme entre las partes.

**Clase AsyncServer**

```
public class AsyncServer
{
    //private bool _anyIp;
    private IPEndPoint _endPoint;
    private TcpListener listener;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private bool _isActive;
    private NetworkStream networkStream;
    private StreamReader reader;
    private StreamWriter writer;

    public IPEndPoint EndPoint { get { return _endPoint; }  }

    public bool IsActive  { get { return _isActive; } }

    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
    public event EventHandler<DataSentEventArgs> DataSent;

    #region Constructores
    public AsyncServer(int port) : this(true, port) { }
    public AsyncServer(bool anyIp, int port, IPAddress ipaddress = null)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        if (!anyIp && ipaddress == null) throw new ArgumentException("IP Address must be specified");

        //_anyIp = anyIp;
        _endPoint = new IPEndPoint(anyIp ? IPAddress.Any : ipaddress, port);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Métodos públicos
    public async void Run()
    {
        if (_endPoint == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (!_isActive)
            try
            {
                _isActive = true;
                listener = new TcpListener(_endPoint);
                listener.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().WithCancellation(cts.Token);
                    await ProcessCommand(client);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { 
                throw; 
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Stop();
            }
    }

    private async Task ProcessCommand(TcpClient tcpClient)
    { 
        string clientEndPoint = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        if (tcpClient.Client.Connected)
            try
            {
                networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
                writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                writer.AutoFlush = true;

                while (true)
                {
                    string command = await Receive();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw ;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (tcpClient.Connected)
                    tcpClient.Close();
            }
    }

     public async void Stop()
    {
        _isActive = false;
        cts.Cancel();
        await SendData("Shutting down server...");
        listener.Stop();
    }

    private async Task SendData(string data)
    {
        await writer.WriteLineAsync(data);

        //Disparamos evento
        DataSent(this, new DataSentEventArgs(data));
    }
    #endregion

    #region Métodos privados
    private async Task<string> Receive()
    {
        var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        DataReceived(this, new DataReceivedEventArgs(data));
        return data;
    }

    #region Eventos ThreadSafe
    private void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> handler = DataReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void OnDataSent(DataSentEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<DataSentEventArgs> handler = DataSent;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion

}
```

**Clase AsyncClient**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace FavSync.Core
{
    public class AsyncClient
    {
        public bool Connected;
        private TcpClient client;
        private NetworkStream networkStream;
        private StreamReader reader;
        private StreamWriter writer;

        public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
        public event EventHandler<DataSentEventArgs> DataSent;

        #region Constructor 
        public AsyncClient()
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            Connected = false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Método públicos
        public async Task ConnectAsync(string server, int port)
        {
            if (client.Connected) throw new InvalidOperationException("Allready connected");

            try
            {
                IPAddress ipAddress = null;
                IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
                for (int i = 0; i < ipHostEntry.AddressList.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ipHostEntry.AddressList[i].AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (ipAddress == null)
                    throw new Exception("Server not found!");
                await client.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, port);
                networkStream = client.GetStream();
                writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                reader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
                writer.AutoFlush = true;
                await SendData("Connected from client");
                Connected = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public async void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string response = await Receive();
            }
        }

        public async Task SendData(string data)
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(data);
            OnDataSent(new DataSentEventArgs(data));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Métodos privados

        private async Task<string> Receive()
        {
            var data = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
            OnDataReceived(new DataReceivedEventArgs(data));
            return data;
        }

        #region Eventos ThreadSafe
        private void OnDataReceived(DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> handler = DataReceived;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        private void OnDataSent(DataSentEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<DataSentEventArgs> handler = DataSent;
            if (handler != null)
                DataSent(this, e);
        }
        #endregion
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**USO:**

```
    AsyncServer server = new AsyncServer(port);
    server.DataReceived += server_DataReceived;
    server.DataSent += server_DataSent;
    server.Run();

    AsyncClient client = new AsyncClient();
    client.DataReceived += client_DataReceived;
    client.DataSent += client_DataSent;
    await client.ConnectAsync(server, port);
    client.Run();
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que al preguntar, mostraras tu codigo, mostraras tu esfuerzo y al tiempo ir planteando las dudas, asi seria mas facil ayudarte.

Comment: Realmente no entiendo la necesidad de hacer algo generico, si deberas programar del otro lado lo que pasa.. sea cual sea el comando...

Comment: @gbianchi para evitar el uso de if's en el otro lado y poder hacerlo más extensible en el futuro sin necesidad programar nada más que lo que tenga que hacer el comando en sí.